# Scalaz state monad exercise to model sampling of coloured balls

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz

Here is a self imposed exercise and solution to learn Scalaz state monad.  How can I refactor it to take it to the next level?  So far I've only studied the state monad so would welcome suggestions on introducing other Scalaz features of relevance, as well as general Scala style/approach.

**Exercise**

> Use state monad to simulate the process of drawing 5 coloured balls
>   from a bag of 30x Red, 20x Green, 10x Blue.  Rather than representing
>   the bag and sample as collections of balls, use a map to track the
>   number of each colour.

**Solution**

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

object StateExercise extends App{
    trait Colour
    object Red extends Colour { override def toString = "Red"}
    object Green extends Colour { override def toString = "Green"}
    object Blue extends Colour { override def toString = "Blue"}

    type Bag = Map[Colour, Int]
    val empty: State[Bag, Bag] = state(Map[Colour, Int]())

    def drawOne(soFar: Bag): State[Bag, Bag] = for(
        ball <- State[Bag, Colour]{s =>
            val (colours, counts) = s.toIndexedSeq.unzip
            val ballIndex = (math.random * s.values.sum).toInt
            val selected = colours(
                counts.tail
                    .view
                    .scanLeft(counts(0))(_ + _)
                    .indexWhere(_ >= ballIndex)
            )
            (s.updated(selected, s(selected) - 1), selected)
        }
    ) yield soFar.updated(ball, soFar.getOrElse(ball, 0) + 1)

    def draw(n: Int): State[Bag, Bag] = for(
        balls <- get[Bag];
        selection <- {
            assert(balls.values.sum >= n)   //Check the bag has enough left
            (1 to n).foldLeft(empty)((accState, _) => accState.flatMap(drawOne))
        }
    ) yield selection

    val full: Bag = Map(Red -> 30, Green -> 20, Blue -> 10)
    val (remaining, selected) = draw(5)(full)
    println(" Selected: "+selected)
    println("Remaining: "+remaining)
}
```

**Output**

> Selected: Map(Red -> 3, Green -> 2)
>
> Remaining: Map(Red -> 27, Green -> 18, Blue -> 10)